# HTML to Classic ASP - Page Loads as Lines of Code (ASP)

Tags: php, html, asp-classic

So I am working with: 
http://glustik.com/essex/index.html

and trying to make it ASP like this:
http://glustik.com/essex/index.asp

But the ASP just loads as code. I want to use some TXT includes is why I am doing this, but it always seems to load just lines of code and not render.

What am I missing here? Please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include files, just use `<?php include 'file.txt' ?>` instead of `<!--#include file="file.txt"-->`.

From your previous questions I've answered, I know that your usual webserver is IIS (and you like to use Classic ASP), but the one you're using now is Apache, which will support PHP (and so [PHP includes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)).

Comment: so do I keep the files as HTML and just use the <?php include 'file.txt' ?> in place of <!--#include file="file.txt"--> when I was using .asp pages?

Comment: @Varazi - As long as you don't have ASP-specific tags, you should be fine.

Comment: @Varazi: Yes. Also: rename all files involved to have a `.php` extension.

Comment: @thirtydot - If they're just reusable markup components, why go through the trouble?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: He'll need a `.php` extension to use the PHP includes. Of course, he could always tell Apache to parse `.html` as PHP, but that's (of course) more complicated than just renaming all files to have a `.php` extension.

Comment: @thirtydot - Ah, I see what you're saying. I was thinking of the included components. I'm cross-eyed on my comments on this question.

Answer (score 3):

ASP is a Microsoft technology.
You need to run IIS, not Apache.

It's also <strike>totally</strike> dead.
You need to use ASP.Net, not ASP.

You could also use PHP instead, if you really want to.

Comment: How do you know it's Apache? I don't see it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Just go to a random page at the same URL to see a 404 page; the server reports what it's running, e.g. http://glustik.com/essex/random.404

Comment: @Jared Farrish: It's in the response headers, check Firebug or similar: `Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 mod_bwlimited/1.4`.

Comment: Classic ASP is not "totally dead" it's alive and well and supported by Microsoft

Comment: Classic ASP reminds me of Windows XP - simple and good product that is not longer officially supported but still used by great many people and websites.

Answer (score 1):

A handler for `.asp` files hasn't been defined in your Apache server's configuration. To execute Classic ASP files on an Apache server, I suggest you have a look at [Sun ONE Active Server Pages 4.01](http://www.sun.com/download/products.xml?id=3f4e6fe6).